# How does overload resolution work for std::vector<int>::insert

Tags: c++, templates

These are two out of three `insert` method signatures from std::vector:

```
void insert (iterator position, size_type n, const value_type& val);
template <class InputIterator>
void insert (iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

Now, given a vector and an insert call,

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.insert( v.begin(), 3, 3 );
```

how come that the 1st `insert` is chosen and not the second one?

I have - naively, I'm sure - implemented the same signatures, but here the second (templated) form was chosen by the compiler.

```
template <class T, int MAXSIZE>
class svector {
public:
  class iterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag,T> { ... };

    // ...

  void insert (class iterator position, size_t n, const T& val){
    if( len + n > MAXSIZE ) throw std::out_of_range( "insert exceeds MAXSIZE" );
    uint32_t iPos = position - begin();
    uint32_t movlen = len - iPos + 1;
    for( uint32_t i = 0; i < movlen; i++ ){
      ele[len + n - i] = ele[len - i];
    }
    for( uint32_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
      ele[iPos + i] = val;
    }
    len += n;
  }

  template <class InputIterator>
  void insert (class iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last){
    for( InputIterator it = first; it != last; it++ ){
      if( len + 1 > MAXSIZE ) throw std::out_of_range( "insert exceeds MAXSIZE" );
      *position = *reinterpret_cast<T*>( it );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Show us your exact code. It's probably _not_ the same signature.

Comment: @stefan Actually it probably is. The second signature *will* be chosen unless you take precautions. The standard specifies that, and also that precautions have to be taken.

Comment: @KonradRudolph it's maybe the same as shown here, but at least in the standard library that comes with g++-4.8.1, there is a second template parameter `typename = std::_RequireInputIter<_InputIterator>`. So it's not the same signature as in vector.

Comment: There's a slight deviation (size_t/ype), but that shouldn't matter. @KonradRudolph Anywhere I can find this on the web?

Comment: @stefan That’s the point. The signature posted by OP is that specified by the standard. The one you’ve posted is an implementation detail, which sounds paradoxical – how can a part of the *interface* be an implementation detail? – but that’s how C++ works.

Comment: `./c++/4.3/debug/vector` does not contain std::_RequireInputIter - or would it be in a different header file?

Comment: @laune Oh wow. GCC 4.3 is *ancient*! You should upgrade your compiler.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Circumstances forbid an upgrade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your reading, and the compiler, are entirely correct.

The standard library implementation has to take precautions (via `std::enable_if` or more generally via [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error)) to ensure that the second overload is chosen *only* for iterator types.

Comment: +1, 23.2.3/14:  *If the member functions of the forms: [...] `rt fx1(const_iterator p, InputIterator first, InputIterator last);`
[...] are called with a type InputIterator that does not qualify as an input iterator, then these functions shall not participate in overload resolution.*

Comment: @jrok: nice footnote :x